# matlab gui becomes unresponsive or partially closes

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am currently working on a matlab gui and after some beginner's problems with the data handling I am quite satisfied with the result.

There is just one hiccup: whenever the program is done running, the gui becomes unresponsive and the buttons and text elements vanish, all I can see is the background.

I have scanned the functions thoroughly for close all; statements and such, but there is nothing there.

How do I return 'clean' to the gui so I can put in more data? Do I need to put the gui in a constant while loop?

best wishes 
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

Modify the attribute of your controls to be interruptible:

```
set(handles.figure, 'Interruptible','on');
```

Create a callback function based on pressing a determined key combination.

```
set(KeyPressFcn, @resume_fcn);
```

Create a callback function that solves the problem.

```
function resume_fcn()
  if eventdata.Key = ...
    exit; 
  end
end
```

However, the consistency of data may be lost. In case you don't want to return 'clean' to the gui, you can type:

```
delete(get(0,'Children'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I will try this when I get into work today!

Can you however explain to my, why the gui 'shuts down' in the first place? shouldnt it be running until I chose to close it?

cheers,

Comment: I'm not sure that this was the question asked... If, as has been assumed, the UI is becoming unresponsive while running some computation, this is because MATLAB will not process the events queue while there is other code running. In this case you could add a call to drawnow somewhere in your loop. If this is not the case, and your GUI is 'disappearing' after the computation, then you are almost certainly causing this with some errant line of code and you should step through your code with the debugger to find the offending line.